# Filter kendo dropdownlist to remove options

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I want to filter security questions such that if I select questiona from the list of questions, for the next questions, I no longer see questiona in the list of security questions. This is to prevent duplicate selection of security questions.

Here's a jsfiddle with a pure jquery implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/jbfbxvoo/

I was wondering how I can use the same approach to filter kendo dropdownlists:

E.g. I have three dropdownlists like:

```
<table style="float: left; width:300px;">
             <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">  
                              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Q1Id).HtmlAttributes(
                              new { style = "width:250px;", @id = "idQuestion1", @class="security"})
                                  .Name("Q1DropDown")
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .BindTo(Controllers.AccountController.SecurityQuestionList())
                                  .Enable(true)
                                  .Events(e=>e.Change("CreateAccount.QuestionChanged")))
                     </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">  
                              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A1, new { @class = "formTextbox k-textbox", @id = "idAnswer1" })
                           </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">  
                              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Q2Id).HtmlAttributes(
                              new { style = "width:250px;", @id = "idQuestion2", @class="security" })
                                  .Name("Q2DropDown")
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .BindTo(Controllers.AccountController.SecurityQuestionList())
                                  .Enable(true)
                                  .Events(e=>e.Change("CreateAccount.QuestionChanged")))
                          </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                      <div class="editor-field">  
                              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A2, new { @class = "formTextbox k-textbox", @id = "idAnswer2" })                              
                           </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                     <div class="editor-field">  
                              @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Q3Id).HtmlAttributes(
                              new { style = "width:250px;", @id = "idQuestion3", @class="security" })
                                  .Name("Q3DropDown")
                                  .DataTextField("Text")
                                  .DataValueField("Value")
                                  .BindTo(Controllers.AccountController.SecurityQuestionList())
                                  .Enable(true)
                                  .Events(e=>e.Change("CreateAccount.QuestionChanged")))
                          </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">  
                              @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A3, new { @class = "formTextbox k-textbox", @id = "idAnswer3" })
                           </div>
                </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
    QuestionChanged: function () {
                var sec = $('.security');
                sec.change(function () {
                    sec.find('option').show().end().each(function () {
                        $('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]:not(:selected):not([value="0"])', sec).hide();
                    });
                }).change();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this implementation i have an idea, where first you need to have 3 dropdownlist that have **one same datasource/observable** but **three different value** to store each dropdownlist value and point to **one same change event**, example in mvvm

```
<h4 class="title">DropDownList</h4>
<input class="customdropdownlist" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="source:dataSource, value:dd1, events:{change:onChange}" style="width: 400px;"/>

<h4 class="title">DropDownList</h4>
<input class="customdropdownlist" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="source:dataSource, value:dd2, events:{change:onChange}" style="width: 400px;"/>

<h4 class="title">DropDownList</h4>
<input class="customdropdownlist" data-role="dropdownlist" data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="source:dataSource, value:dd3, events:{change:onChange}" style="width: 400px;"/>
```

On the view model change event you do your logic, maybe you can write better code than mine right now but the main point is

> To loop through all 3 dropdownlist `<li></li>` , and compare with the
>   three  value dd1,dd2,dd3 hide if match, otherwise show it

And the code :

```
var dropdowns = $("input.customdropdownlist");
for(j=0;j<dropdowns.length;j++){
  var list = $(dropdowns[j]).data("kendoDropDownList").ul.find("li.k-item");
  for(i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    if(viewModel.dd1 &&list[i].textContent == viewModel.dataSource.get(viewModel.dd1).text){
      $(list[i]).hide();
    }else if(viewModel.dd2 &&list[i].textContent == viewModel.dataSource.get(viewModel.dd2).text){
      $(list[i]).hide();
    }else if(viewModel.dd3 &&list[i].textContent == viewModel.dataSource.get(viewModel.dd3).text){
        $(list[i]).hide();
    }else{
        $(list[i]).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Working example in [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EvoTE), add
updated [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EvoTE/2) from modifying your code.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. However, I am using MVC. So I suppose the logic would have to be in my controller or can I do it in js?

Comment: what is dd1, dd2, dd3? Why do yo have viewmodel.dd1, etc..? Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You dont have to follow my code as i dont use mvc, but i think you can do it on javascript on your QuestionChanged function as it client side validation (sort of). Just get the value of dd1,dd2,dd3 (it is the value of the selected option from each dropdown) do loop through all dropdown list option and show/hide as the condition match

Comment: I think you're onto something I tried to follow the js code you posted but I got stuck on the viewmodel.dd1, dd2, etc... So just for clarity, for viewModel.dd1, that is the selected value of the dropdownlist right? So in the if statement, it would be like (in semi-pseudocode), if(selectedRow && list[i].textContent == selectedRow.text) { $(list[i]).hide();}, etc... Something like that? Just trying to understand your if statement and how I can adapt it into my situation. Thanks!

Comment: dd1 is the selected value for the first dropdownlist, dd2 for the second, dd3 for the third. As for my "if condition" first check if dd1 has a value (making sure it is not null, undefined or just empty) and if current dropdownlist option text match any of (dd1,dd2,dd3) but since dd1,dd2,dd3 is integer value i need to get the text from datasource

Comment: I'm guessing I have to do something similar to the api.cshtml demo here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/api

Comment: Horrible attempt but: http://pastebin.com/M5dBGhcU something like that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I will try it first, update it later. cant do it now

Comment: @KalaJ i already update my answer based your attempt, you just missed that you need the two other dropdownlist value and compare them too. Take a look at the second dojo provided

Comment: machun, what if I wanted to get the selected value of the dropdownlist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990986/how-to-get-selected-value-of-kendo-dropdownlist-on-change

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar for kendo ComboBox. Do manipulate the below js function and it will work for kendo Drop Down also.

```
function QuestionChanged(event) {
  $("[class^=security]").each(function () {
     if (event.sender.element.attr('class') != $(this).attr('class')) {
        var comboBox = $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).data('kendoComboBox');
        $(comboBox.dataSource.data()).each(function () {
            if (event.sender._selectedValue == this.Value) {
                var data = this;
                comboBox.dataSource.remove(data);
            }
        });
     }
  });
}
```

**NOTE:** Add ***security*** class to each of the drop down as security1 for first drop down, security2 for 2nd drop down and so on.

Hope it helps! Feel free to leave your feedback.

Comment: security1, security2, so different classes  for each dropdownlist?

Comment: okay I see the issue, kind of. I can see and select the repeat quesiton in the dropdownlist but when I go and select it, it appears as a non-repeat question selected. Strange behavior.

Comment: This is how I am binding questions to my kendo dropdownlist: http://pastebin.com/2P3sRWnZ